# DISPROVING "Every odd positive integer is the sum of a prime number and twice the square of an integer"

Tags: logic, examples-counterexamples, solution-verification, theorem-provers

Providing a counter-example is enough to disprove a statement. However, it is not the only we of disproving. For example, if the statement is "$\sqrt{2}$ is a rational number", then we can disprove it by the way of contradiction, where we assume it is true and using some mathematical concepts and operation which will conclude that our assumption (that the statement is true) is a wrong assumption.

> My question is, how to disprove the following statement, not by
>   providing a counter-example: "every odd positive integer is the sum of
>   a prime number and twice the square of an integer"?

By giving a counter example, we can say "$5777$ does not satisfy the given statement".

I am in need of your help because it is difficult to find a counter-example.

Any help of disproving the given statement would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: @OscarLanzi $3=3+2\cdot 0^2$.

Comment: @Arthur Check your arithmetic.

Comment: What do you mean by "disproving but without giving a counterexample"?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari I think my arithmetic is fine and shows that the positive odd integer $3$ is the sum of a prime ($3$) and twice a square ($2\cdot 0^2$), so $3$ is therefore not a counterexample. On the other hand, your $3 = 2 + 1^2$ is not writing $3$ as a sum of a prime and twice a square, so it doesn't suffice to demonstrate that $3$ isn't a counterexample.

Comment: @Marktmeister I mean, giving a counter-example is not the only way to disprove a statement. I prefer to use another way since giving a counter-example is difficult in some cases. Can we use contradiction here for example?

Comment: If we can find a counterexample in this case then?

Comment: @Arthur You are right.

Comment: Wait... how do you know it is false... Maybe it's true?

Comment: @aman Note that a prime number is always positive, and twice the square of an integer is always non-negative, in this case, we can check the primes that are less than $5777$. This is called "Proof by EXHAUSTION" or by "CASES".

Comment: So what you are asking is WHY the first counterexample comes at 5777 if I understood correctly

Comment: $5993$ seems to be the next

Comment: @aman Sorry if my English is poor since I am Arabic person. What I mean, in general, how can we use other way to disprove ANY false statement? Say the statement is "any positive number is less than its square", we can disprove this by giving a counter-example, say $\frac{1}{2}$ is greater than its square $\frac{1}{4}$. The way I want is as follows: The statement is "$x<x^2$ for +ve $x$", so $1<x$ for +ve $x$, but this is false, because $1>x$ is true for some +ve "$x$" as well. Hence we disproved the statement.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for commenting. If you do not understand the question, here is another way of asking it: Without giving a counter example, show that the statement "Every odd positive integer is the sum of a prime number and twice the square of an integer" is false.

Comment: I don't see an easy way of doing that, though of course it is logically possible.  A  natural thought would be to show that there weren't "enough" such representations but that does not appear to be true. At least, I don't see how to show otherwise.  I really think counterexample is the best way to go.

Comment: Mind you, don't try to find the next counterexample after $1$, $5777$ and $5993$ ... See OEIS [A060003](https://oeis.org/A060003).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to simply prove by brute force.
This statement says that:
$n= p + 2k^2$, for n - odd positive integer, with p being a prime, and k - integer.
If $n= p + 2k^2$, then $n-2k^2$>$0$, for there to exist a prime number p (since primes can only be positive). 
As such we can create a set of witnesses $W_n$, where:

$W_n$ = { $n - 2k^2$ | $k = 1,2,3,... , \lfloor \sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} \rfloor$}.

As such, to disprove this we must find the lowest n such that $P_n$ $\cap$ $W_n$= $\emptyset$, with $P_n$ being a set of primes smaller than n.

To find an efficient solution, we must start from n=9, as the smallest odd composite number and check that all primes $p$ $\in$ $P_n$ can be used to make $\frac{n-p}{2}$ = $k^2$.

I have written a C++ program to find a counter-example.
Here it is:

bool isPrime(int x)

{

```
if (x < 2 || (x > 2 && x % 2 == 0))

    return false;

for (int d = 3; d * d <= x; d += 2)

    if (x % d == 0)

        return false;

return true;
```

}

int main()

{

```
int found = 0, n, count = 0;

for (n = 9; found == 0; n += 2)

{

    count = 0;

    cout << n << "= ";

    if (isPrime(n) == 0)

    {

        found = 1;

        for (int k = 1; 2 * k * k <= n; k++)

            if (isPrime(n - 2 * k * k) == 1)

            {

                found = 0;

                if (count == 0)

                {

                    cout << n - 2 * k * k << " + 2*" << k << "^2" << endl;

                    count = 1;

                }



            }

    }

}

cout << endl << "For value " << n-2 << " the statement was not true";

return 0;
```

}

Note: The easiest solution is to disprove it using a counter-example.

Comment: The following program is for every odd COMPOSITE number. The first counter-example is, as you stated, 5777.

Comment: $n-2k^2>0$ , $\Rightarrow$ $-2k^2>-n$ $\Rightarrow$ $2k^2<n$ $\Rightarrow$ $k^2<frac{n}{2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $k<\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$. But k $\in$ Z, so k< $\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} \rfloor$.